# Calculate the average of a subsample with cast in R reshape2

Tags: r, reshape2

I am attempting to calculate the average of a subsample with the function acast. As the subsample, I want to use data within a percentile range for which I use quantile within the subset. The problem seems that the quantiles are calculated before arranging the data by groups, thus the same values are used. See the example below:

library(reshape2)

```
library(plyr) 
data(airquality)
aqm <- melt(airquality, id=c("Month", "Day"), na.rm=TRUE)
## here I calculate the length for each group for the whole sample
acast(aqm, variable + Month ~ . , length, value.var = "value")
## here I calculate the length for the range within the quantiles 0.05 - 0.5
acast(aqm, variable + Month ~ . , length, value.var = "value",  subset = .(value >= quantile(value,c(0.05)) & value <= quantile(value,c(0.5))))
```

I should get with the subset half of the observations for each group, but instead I get in some cases way lees than half and in other way more. It seems to me that the quantiles are calculated with the melted data, therefore the function applies the same quantile numbers to all groups. 
Does anyone have an idea how to make that the quantiles are calculates for each group? Any help would be appreciated. I know this would be possible by doing a loop by categories, but want to see if there is a way to do it all at once.

Thanks,

Sergio René

Comment: Perhaps this helps `library(data.table);dcast(melt(setDT(airquality), id=c("Month", "Day"), na.rm=TRUE)[value >= quantile(value, 0.05) & value <= quantile(value, 0.5), .SD, .(variable, Month)], variable + Month ~..., length)`

Comment: Thanks, actually teh idea of making the subset directly on the data rather than in the dcast fundtion did the work.